# Detect low res android devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I want to be able to detect if the current user is using a low-res ( < 320px) device and load a different stylesheet for that user. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find many articles on the web explaining how you can build good website designs for smartphones.

To answer your case, you can find several ways to handle it:

**Media Queries**

Since CSS3, you can use the `max-width` or the `device-width`.

That would give something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
    href="shetland.css" />
```

**JavaScript**

You can use javascript to check the browser width.

Here is an example using jquery:

```
if ($(window).width() < 320) {
   $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "mobile.css"});
} else {
   $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "desktop.css"});
}
```

**Going further**

Here are a few interesting and useful links:

- [Responsive web Design on Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)
- [Detect Mobile Devices on about.com](http://webdesign.about.com/od/mobile/a/detect-mobile-devices.htm)
- [An older article (but where you can find some useful tips too](http://www.tomw.net.au/2006/wd/smartphone.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Well first you detect the monitor's resolution with `screen.width` and `screen.height`.

```
if (screen.width < 320 || screen.height < 320) {
    ....
}
```

Then you need to actually load the stylesheets. The easiest way is to include this outside of any loader or anything so you can just `document.write` it.

```
if (screen.width < 320 || screen.height < 320) {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" src="lowres.css"></script>');
} else {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" src="desktop.css"></script>');
}
```